# PHP exec command using pgrep return value incorrect

Tags: php, exec, grep

I have a php script with the following command I am running:

```
exec("pgrep -fl ./build-dh", $output, $return);
```

pgrep usually returns "1" if it does not find a "./build-dh" process running, however, it is always returning "0", even when I am positive the process is not running.

Here is what I get from $output:

```
Array ( [0] => 28560 sh -c pgrep -fl ./build-dh )
```

This means that it is outputting its' own pid, which I guess forces a "0" return code no matter what.  When I run the following in the shell, it works fine:

```
$pgrep -fl ./build-dh
$echo $?
1
```

So the return value works fine... and when I run this:

```
 $pgrep -f nginx
11192
11193
11194
11195
11196
$echo $?
0
```

How can I get this working correctly in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: try to type the full-path to `build-dh`

Comment: Shouldn't matter since pgrep is searching running processes, not starting anything, no path is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, it does not take much to fix `$output` and `$result` from exec to more closely resemble what you get in the CLI:

```
foreach($output as $oi=>$o) if(strpos($o,'pgrep')!==false) unset($output[$oi]);
$return = !count($output);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better than what I was going to do which was just throw away the first result and figure every time that the first result was itself.  Just bugged me that it wasn't working in php like it should.

Comment: Yeah I found it a little strange as well. But honestly I was more surprised that the CLI does not show the pgrep. I tend to do a ps piped to grep rather than a pgrep, so I am used to seeing grep in the results. .. A great question BTW.

Comment: Yeah, I was using pgrep specifically because it didn't show that in the CLI :D.  I was originally prepared to use "ps aux | grep ./build-dh | grep -v grep" to see if that worked without issues.  However I was so fixated on the pgrep didn't even try it :D